# scipy.optimize.minimize: Alternatively optimize a loss function with respect to two parameters

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, minimize

I have a loss function E(v,c), where v,c, are vectors.

```
def loss(v,c,a):
    ...
    return loss_value
```

In the first step i want to minimize over the vector v, then in the second step minimize over the vector c by using the minimized vector v_hat in the previous step. 
for ex:

```
v_hat.x = minimize(loss,v,args = (c,a))
c_hat.x = minimize(loss,c,args = (v_hat.x,a)) ###error
```

The problem is scipy.optimize.minimize takes the input arguments in order i.e. it knows it is always the first argument in the arguments of loss function which has to be minimized. If i want to minimize the second argument, I would either have to write another loss function with the second argument at first place: like

```
def loss_2(c,v,a):
    ...
    return loss_value
```

now i can write the second statement by changing the name of the loss function. But this is a clumsy way, any approach to do this in a better way ?

Comment: Use a parameter, which extracts the values to work on in the first line of the cost-function. But i would keep it splitted into two cost-functions.

Comment: @sascha you mean i should pack the arguments v,c in a vector then unpack inside the cost function ?

Comment: Ah skip that. This sounds bad on second thought. Just write 2 different optimize-wrappers and call them with two different losses and 2 different opt-vectors. Which one is called how is part of your alternating-direction loop.